# rake db:seed generates ArgumentError: missing keywords: from, to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I got a database to seed to test my code. When I run `rake db:seed` to seed the database, I get the error below.

I expected the console to be blank: this means the data has been seeded.

Error:

```
[19:19:41] (master) simple-partials-lab-noukod-000
// ♥ rake db:seed
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/duplicable.rb:111: warning: BigDecimal.new is deprecated; use BigDecimal() method instead.
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: missing keywords: from, to
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/faker-2.2.1/lib/faker/default/date.rb:6:in `between'
/home/considerate-transform-1229/simple-partials-lab-noukod-000/db/seeds.rb:9:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/considerate-transform-1229/simple-partials-lab-noukod-000/db/seeds.rb:8:in `times'
/home/considerate-transform-1229/simple-partials-lab-noukod-000/db/seeds.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:547:in `load_seed'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:253:in `load_seed'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:173:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-12.3.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: `ArgumentError: missing keywords: from, to` is the important part I think.  Can you post the seed file?

Comment: Please provide your seed.rb code

Answer (score 9):

Looks like you're using `Faker` with the old syntax. It recently changed to require keyword arguments rather than positional arguments.

You need to follow the updated syntax:

```
Faker::Date.between(from: 2.days.ago, to: Date.today) #=> "Wed, 24 Sep 2014"
```

Note the keywords `from:` and `to:` which specify the arguments. Order of arguments is not important, and the reverse order will work just the same:

```
Faker::Date.between(to: Date.today, from: 2.days.ago) #=> "Wed, 24 Sep 2014"
```

Additional information available in their docs: https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker/blob/master/doc/default/date.md