# ArgumentError in FactoryBot build method in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Good morning all,

I am following an online course from Udemy, in the latter portion of the course, we learned to use FactoryBot. At this moment, I'm having an error in `irb` on `FactoryBot.build(:book)` method

```
irb(main):001:0> FactoryBot.build(:book)
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
ArgumentError (missing keywords: from, to)
```

I don't find out why, because, first of all, I followed the course to the letter (I came back to it several times). Secondly, I have the same version as the trainer:
`2.5.1`

Comment: Check the rest of that stack trace which will tell you more specifically where the issue is raised. My guess is that you have overridden one of the methods in your model.

Comment: Excuse me, but I do not understand your return ...

Comment: 2.5.1 is the ruby version, right? what's the Rails version?

Comment: Hello, 

The Rails version is : Rails 6.0.3.3

Thanks you :)

Comment: may be similar to - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58633069/rake-dbseed-generates-argumenterror-missing-keywords-from-to

Comment: Yeah! I nevertheless searched for a long time! Thank you, it's resolved thanks to you @Sampat!